# Headphone/Speaker mixup after upgrading to 11.10 with a Realtek ALC892

Tags: 11.10, sound, headphones

It seems quite a few people have trouble with their speakers/headphones after upgrading tu ubuntu 10.10, but my problem is slightly different.

I have a desktop pc with a Realtek ALC892.

I have no speakers connected to the computer, but occasionally plug headphones into the front jack. When I do this, the field "connector" in the sound settings dialog switches from "analog speakers" to "analog headphones", but then I hear no sound at all through the headphones. Only when I manually switch said field back to "analog speakers" can I hear something.

The funny thing: If I plug in the headphones and try to fiddle with the controls in alsamixer (which means trying out setting different levels for different devices) nothing happens. The *only* way to get sound on my headphones is to always manually switch the "connector" to "analog speakers" in the dialog box.

I did not have these troubles in Ubuntu 11.04.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same issue and installed the latest Alsa driver : 
see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS
and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/565685